# Replace Bootstrap default css

Tags: divshot

I am trying out divshot for to evaluate if we can use it for our company, but have one question. Our company uses a custom version of bootstrap, is there a way to specify a "theme" for bootsrap or to replace the bootstrap default css? I've basically ripped all drop shadows and border radius from everything and made the styles more flat. Just wanted to know if we could over ride that default bootstrap stylesheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can upload a custom bootstrap.css file into your project and then simply replace the `<link>` tag in any Divshot HTML page with a relative link. So if I uploaded my custom theme to `css/my-bootstrap.css` in the project, I could then link it like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-bootstrap.css">
```